# Jekyll/Poet blog - remote path for markdown files?

Tags: node.js, blogs, jekyll

I am going to deploy my blog, which is based on [Poet](http://jsantell.github.io/poet/) (blog generator in node.js), but I am wondering if it's possible to specify remote path for my markdown files. It's similar to Jekyll where you specify the `_posts` directory, it will then read all markdown files in that folder and include them in your blog.

Why would I need a remote directory? Because I don't want to do this every single time:

```
git add _posts/06-24-2013-new-post.markdown
git commit -m 'added new blog post'
git push
```

I simply want to drag and drop my markdown file into my Dropbox or Amazon S3 and have Poet automatically read those files.

Surely people have done something like that before?

Here is the *Poet's* config object. Can I change `posts` to point to `me.s3.amazonaws.com/_posts/` or my *Public* Dropbox folder?

```
poet.set({
  posts: './_posts/', // where all .markdown files are stored
  postsPerPage: 5,
  metaFormat: 'json'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we are using stackedit (and publishing to the local dir via ssh), but poet has a fault: check issues [#15](https://github.com/jsantell/poet/issues/15) and [#27](https://github.com/jsantell/poet/pull/27).

we are using these blog engine [(here)](https://github.com/rgrove/lectroid) cause these.

#### [StackEdit Github Repo](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/)

#### [Demo](http://benweet.github.io/stackedit/)

### Some Features:

#### StackEdit can:

- Manage multiple Markdown documents online or offline
- Export your documents in Markdown or HTML and format it using a template
- Synchronize your Markdown documents in the Cloud
- Edit existing Markdown documents from Google Drive, Dropbox and your local hard drive
- Post your Markdown document on Blogger/Blogspot, WordPress, Tumblr
- Publish your Markdown document on GitHub, Gist, Google Drive, Dropbox or any SSH server
- Share a link to a Markdown document that renders it in a nice viewer
- Show statistics about your document
- Convert HTML to Markdown

#### Features:

- Real-time HTML preview with Scroll Link feature to bind editor and preview scrollbars
- Markdown Extra support and Prettify syntax highlighting
- LaTeX mathematical expressions using MathJax
- WYSIWYG control buttons
- Configurable layout
- Theming support with multiple themes available
- A la carte extensions
- Offline editing
- Online synchronization using Google Drive and Dropbox
- One click publish on Blogger, Dropbox, Gist, GitHub, Google Drive, SSH server, Tumblr, WordPress

Comment: Thanks I will definitely check out StackEdit.

Comment: Creator of Poet here, posts now auto-reload! :)